# Right anchor of UIScrollView does not apply

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, constraints

I have a `UIViewController?` **SingleEventController** displaying Events. Because it has dynamic information to show, I chose to create a new class `UIScrollView` **EventScrollView**. I tried to realize that based on this very well explained
[Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21633185/10151464)
I tried to apply the Pure Auto Layout Approach: Create another `UIView` **contentView** in it, which contains all the information and is anchored to all four anchors of the scrollView.

The contentSize of the scrollView is determined in the *viewDidLayoutSubviews* function in the SingleEventController.

My struggle is, that the rightAnchor seems to be faulty. All the information-Elements go over the border of the view, the word-wrapping for the larger `UILabels` does not work, and every Item layed out at the right anchor is gone. (For example the usernames in the `UITableView` **nopePeopleTV** which is a subview of the contentView.)

This looks like this:
[image: Problem-Image]

---

Code in the **SingleEventController:**

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: buttonViewDividerView.topAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    let heightOfAllObjects = scrollView.calculateHeightOfAllObjects()
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: heightOfAllObjects + scrollView.heightOfAllPaddings)
}
```

Code in **EventScrollView**:

```
addSubview(contentView)
contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
contentView.addSubview(locationLabel)
...
contentView.addSubview(nopePeopleTV)

contentView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
titleLabel.anchor(top: contentView.topAnchor, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: contentView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: padding, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: padding, width: 0, height: 0)
locationLabel.anchor(top: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: padding, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 200, height: 0)
nopePeopleTV.anchor(top: maybePeopleTV.bottomAnchor, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: contentView.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

layoutIfNeeded()
contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

My anchor function looks like this:

```
func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,  paddingTop: CGFloat, paddingLeft: CGFloat, paddingBottom: CGFloat, paddingRight: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    if let top = top {
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true
    }

    if let left = left {
        leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true
    }

    if let right = right {
        rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true
    }

    if width != 0 {
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
    }

    if height != 0 {
        heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you would please stop interposing some third party library that is evidently being used to form the constraints.

Comment: If you want to see 5 lines of code, that are always the same..

Comment: That's better than one line of code that I don't understand.

Comment: Understandable. I added the function now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are letting the content view width be dictated from the inside out by the width of the subviews. You need to give the content view a width constraint matching the width of the scroll view itself.

I'll demonstrate the difference with an artificial but complete code-only example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(sv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        let cv = UIView() // content view
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.addSubview(cv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.topAnchor),
            sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.leadingAnchor),
            sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.trailingAnchor),
            sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        let lab = UILabel()
        lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lab.numberOfLines = 0
        lab.text = Array(repeating: "xxx", count: 100).joined(separator: " ")
        cv.addSubview(lab)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            lab.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.topAnchor, constant:30),
            lab.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.leadingAnchor),
            lab.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv.trailingAnchor),
        ])
    }
}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

We have a very long label, but it doesn't wrap: it keeps extending to the right, off the screen. That's because the content view itself has its right edge off the screen. That's because we have done nothing to *prevent* this from happening. The long label is itself making the content view as wide as the label's entire text.

Now I add one final line of code to `viewDidLoad`:

```
    cv.widthAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo:sv.frameLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

The result is this:

[image]

The content view is now the width of the scroll view, so the label wraps within the scroll view.

We do not, however, do the same thing to the *height* of the content view; we *want* it to grow vertically in accordance with its subviews. And that way, we will be able to scroll vertically (which is what you want) but not horizontally (which is also what you want).

Comment: Your "final line of code" fixed my problem! I thank you.